# How to link Window.SizeChanged in a C# Windows 8 App

Tags: c#, resize, windows-store-apps

I don't know how to link use the Window.SizeChanged event properly in developing a C# Windows 8 app.

I have a basic event that I would like to run:

```
private void OnWindowSizeChanged(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowSizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

but I don't know how to make this run when the window's size changes. I tried linking to it on the page element in my XAML file with `SizeChanged="OnWindowSizeChanged"`, but that returns an error (`No overload for 'OnWindowSizeChanged' matches delegate 'Windows.UI.Xaml.SizeChangedEventHandler'`).

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Window.Current.SizeChanged += OnWindowSizeChanged;
```